# Time validation in ionic using ion-datetime

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I am  newbie for this technology,
I have two fields for entering start time and end time 
I have to perform following operation 
1) Start time must be less than current time
2) End time must be greater than start time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P50qt.png)I have taken template reference variable name timeIn and timeOut and I have pass these variable as an argument to the logMessage() function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XswVt.png) I have created function named logMessage() and I have pass two parameters in it for start time and end time  I have followed  this steps to implement. I have no clue what to do further.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? please update your question with some code you attempted to make this work with. Stack Overflow folks are not here to build things for you, but to help guide you.

Comment: Please refer my code